# How to make SQLite to work with Angular 4+, Electron and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to build one small desktop app using:

- Angular 4+
- NodeJS
- Electron
- SQLite3

NodeJS will be used for scanning local user hdd and inserting specific files that are found into SQLite3 database.

I checked dozens of documentation and suggestions. Most of them suggest to use NodeJS Express framework and make layer between Angular 4+ -> Express -> SQLite3.

I want to avoid using Express framework because it is going to be desktop app and it is not needed at all.

What I tried and what I did:

I installed:

```
   "sqlite3": "^3.1.9",
   "node-pre-gyp": "^0.6.36",
```

as dependencies in my project.

Than I have read if you want to use native nodejs library you should run electron rebuild. So I installed also electron rebuild:

```
"electron-rebuild": "^1.6.0"
```

as a devDependencies and run it with following command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

Rebuild sqlite3 successfully finished.

Than I run electron application and I get following error:

```
/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/haris/development/walter/angular-electron-starter/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js'
    at Error (native)
 @ ./~/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js 1:13-36
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.browser.ts
```

I'm stuck here. I tried many more things like:

```
1. Removing node_modules
2. npm install --build-from-source
```

but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: In my limited experience, a common reason for node-gyp / node-pre-gyp to buid is because of missing build-tools. What OS are you on?

Comment: @ippi I'm using Linux / Ubuntu 16.04 ( 64bit ).

Comment: With alpine you need at least `make gcc g++ python` for node-gyp. Not sure about ubuntu.

Comment: (Also I think your real error is elsewhere)

Comment: @ippi I'm struggling more than two days to find where is the problem but still without success. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PottaG did find the solution for the above quetion ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just published a sample project which shows how to build a desktop app using Electron, Angular4 and Sqlite3. You can clone it [here](https://github.com/leota/electron-angular4-sqlite3)

**Note**
I've node-gyp globally installed.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For what it might be worth to others.  I had followed the steps from @leota (very good thank you BTW!).

My problem is I had Python 2.7 x64 version, and *I think* it needed the 32 bit version.. as I installed the standard version, my rebuild process worked fine!